# Как сделать переход на другую страницу, с сохранением состояния на последней?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Пытаюсь сделать квиз-игру на React.js, где при выборе вопроса из списка должен происходить переход на другую страницу (вопроса), на которой нужно дать ответ и вернуться обратно на главную страницу с вопросами. Могу провернуть такое только с помощью модальных окон. А как сделать с переходом на другую страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Вам либо использовать react-router-dom и его апи, или при переходе на другую страницу указывать в ссылке параметры "откуда вы пришли", что-то вроде: `mysite/question1?previospage=quiz1`

Параметры затем считываются и после ответа вы можете вернутся туда, откуда пришли (также указав в ссылке ответ).

Также можно [использовать HOC](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) - данные храним на "верхнем" общем родителе.

Вообще реализация вопросов/ответов отдельными страницами странное решение. Нельзя выбранный вопрос на эту же страницу загрузить что-ли?