# Как сделать переходы по страницам в react с сохранением состояния

Tags: reactjs

Уже задавал похожий вопрос - [Как сделать переход на другую страницу, с сохранением состояния на последней?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088707/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9). Использую Link react-router-dom, но при возвращении назад страница перерисовается заново. Как сохранить состояние? Хранить состояние всей страницы в каком-то хранилище типа redux?

Comment: context, redux, mobx или держать состояние которое нужно сохранить на верхнем уровне и заниматься property drill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да Redux  поможет в этом. 
Даже можно делать несколько Redux stores. При переходе по ссылкам react-router-dom state остаётся.
Или хранить state в компоненте который не размонтируется при переходе по раутам.